# How to mean patterned values in a time series using s/t/l/.. apply family?

Tags: r, apply, lapply

Reproducible example added:

```
set.seed(1)
y <- ts(rnorm(28))
y # the series from which 3+4*i pattern is introduced
mean(c(y[3 + 4*0], y[3 + 4*1], y[3 + 4*2], y[3 + 4*3], y[3+4*4], y[3+4*5], y[3+4*6])) #[1] 0.4326433
```

So, how to find 0.4326433 without all such messy things? 
Note that when the length of the time series is very big, writing this messy is nearly impossible!
By the way, I have the capability of "for" solution to do that; I am not asking "for" solution.

Comment: `mean(y[3+4*(0:6)])#[1] 0.4326433`

Comment: @akrun, It worked. Your solution even did not require the usage of anything! I could not imagine at all that this can be done the way you introduced. You can introduce it as solution. Thx.

Comment: Glad to know that it worked.  Posted as a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
mean(y[3+4*(0:6)])
#[1] 0.4326433
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
mean(y[seq(3, length(y), 4)])
#[1] 0.4326433
```